# Python Pandas: Subsetting data frame both by rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Data frame has `w` (week) and `y` (year) columns.

```
d = {
    'y': [11,11,13,15,15],
    'w': [5, 4, 7, 7, 8],
    'z': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   w   y  z
0  5  11  1
1  4  11  2
2  7  13  3
3  7  15  4
4  8  15  5
```

Two questions:

1) How to get from this data frame min/max date as two numbers `w` and `y`  in a list `[w,y]` ?

2) How to subset both columns and rows, so all `w` and `y` in the resulting data frame are constrained by conditions:

```
11 <= y <= 15
4  <= w <= 7
```

To get min/max pairs I need functions:

```
min_pair() --> [11,4]                                                                                         
max_pair() --> [15,8]
```

and these to get a data frame subset:

```
from_to(y1,w1,y2,w2)                                                                                        
from_to(11,4,15,7) -->
```

should return `rf` data frame like this:

```
r = {
    'y': [11,13,15],
    'w': [4, 7, 7 ],
    'z': [2, 3, 4 ]
}

rf = pd.DataFrame(r)

In [62]: rf
Out[62]:
   w   y  z
0  4  11  2
1  7  13  3
2  7  15  4
```

Are there any standard functions for this?

**Update**

For subsetting the following worked for me:

```
df[(df.y <= 15 ) & (df.y >= 11) & (df.w >= 4) & (df.w <= 7)]
```

a lot of typing though ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of methods

```
In [176]: df.min().tolist()
Out[176]: [4, 11]

In [177]: df.max().tolist()
Out[177]: [8, 15]

In [178]: df.query('11 <= y <= 15 and 4 <= w <= 7')
Out[178]:
   w   y
0  5  11
1  4  11
2  7  13
3  7  15
```

Comment: What if there is another column z? How min will work in this case? Unfortunately this does not work with more complex data: cnt float64,
foo int64,
year int64,
week int64,
bar  float64,
val  float64

Comment: Select only required columns, `df[col_list].min()`, could you elaborate your second part on complex data?

Comment: @zork, this solution should work also with all those dtypes, you've mentioned

Comment: For some reason `query` returns empty set in my case ((

Comment: @zork, does it return an empty set for your sample data set (the one in your question)?

Comment: No, for another set, not in the question.